Diagnostic analyzer runner is currently unavailable doe to an internal error (with CodeRush)
In Visual Studio, when I enable CodeRush and build, I see the error message with stack trace
StreamJsonRpc.RemoteInvocationException: Argument contains duplicate analyzer instances. (Parameter 'analyzers')
   at StreamJsonRpc.JsonRpc.<InvokeCoreAsync>d__156`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Remote.BrokeredServiceConnection`1.<TryInvokeAsync>d__18`1.MoveNext()
RPC server exception:
System.ArgumentException: Argument contains duplicate analyzer instances. (Parameter 'analyzers')
      at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.CompilationWithAnalyzers.VerifyAnalyzersArgumentForStaticApis(ImmutableArray`1 analyzers, Boolean allowDefaultOrEmpty)
      at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.CompilationWithAnalyzers..ctor(Compilation compilation, ImmutableArray`1 analyzers, CompilationWithAnalyzersOptions analysisOptions)
      at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Remote.Diagnostics.DiagnosticComputer.GetDiagnosticsAsync(ImmutableArray`1 projectAnalyzerIds, ImmutableArray`1 hostAnalyzerIds, Boolean reportSuppressedDiagnostics, Boolean logPerformanceInfo, Boolean getTelemetryInfo, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
      at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Remote.Diagnostics.DiagnosticComputer.GetNormalPriorityDiagnosticsAsync(ImmutableArray`1 projectAnalyzerIds, ImmutableArray`1 hostAnalyzerIds, Boolean reportSuppressedDiagnostics, Boolean logPerformanceInfo, Boolean getTelemetryInfo, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
      at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Remote.RemoteDiagnosticAnalyzerService.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<<CalculateDiagnosticsAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
   --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
      at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Remote.RemoteWorkspace.<>c__DisplayClass7_0`1.<<RunWithSolutionAsync>g__ProcessSolutionAsync|1>d.MoveNext()
   --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
      at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Remote.RemoteWorkspace.RunWithSolutionAsync[T](AssetProvider assetProvider, Checksum solutionChecksum, Boolean updatePrimaryBranch, Func`2 implementation, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
      at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Remote.RemoteWorkspace.RunWithSolutionAsync[T](AssetProvider assetProvider, Checksum solutionChecksum, Boolean updatePrimaryBranch, Func`2 implementation, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
      at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Remote.BrokeredServiceBase.RunWithSolutionAsync[T](Checksum solutionChecksum, Func`2 implementation, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
      at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Remote.RemoteDiagnosticAnalyzerService.CalculateDiagnosticsAsync(Checksum solutionChecksum, DiagnosticArguments arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

If I disable CodeRush the problem goes away.
However I want to use CodeRush without this error.
I am running Visual Studio 17.12.3 and CodeRush for VS 2022 24.2.3
